# Scrollbar for outputLabel

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to implment a scrollbar for a outputLabel but if i use scrollbar component it put every list elment in a new row. The whole output should be disyplayed in one row and the list should be scrollable. Can i fix this problem with a CSS attribute?

i use primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.1

here is my code

```
    <p:commandButton id="newMessage" update=":contentForm"
                actionListener="#{taskboxBean.newMessage}" value="New Message" />
            <p:commandButton id="trash"
                update=":contentForm, :postForm:tabViewPosts:trashTable, :postForm:tabViewPosts:inboxTable, :postForm:tabViewPosts:sentTable"
                actionListener="#{taskboxBean.deleteSelectedTaskbox}" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Trash" />

            <p:scrollPanel>
                <ui:repeat var="task_to_user" value="#{taskboxBean.selectedTaskbox.TASKBOX_TO_USERS}">
                    <p:outputLabel
                        value="#{task_to_user.USER.EMAIL}  #{task_to_user.USER.FIRST_NAME} #{task_to_user.USER.LAST_NAME} #{task_to_user.USER.FIRST_NAME}" />
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:scrollPanel>

            <h:outputText value="#{taskboxBean.selectedTaskbox.TASKTYPE.NAME} " />
            <h:outputText value="#{taskboxBean.selectedTaskbox.CREATE_TIMESTAMP} " />
```

Comment: can you share the HTML render code?

Comment: I upload it with a dropbox file one moment

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxbq5cjc21lw20h/html.txt